# Is there a way to turn this small method into a lambda or linq statement?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, reflection, lambda, refactoring

I have the following method:

```
private static object[] GenerateParameters(MethodBase executingMethod)
{
    var parameterInfoList = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    var parameterObjectList = new List<object>();

    for (var i = 0; i < parameterInfoList.Count(); i++)
    {
        parameterObjectList.Add(parameterInfoList.GetValue(i));
    }

    return parameterObjectList.ToArray();
}
```

It just seems to me that is is bloated and over complicated. Is there a way to turn this method into one or two lines of code that will do the same thing? Possibly using Lambda or LINQ.

The reason why I think it is so bloated is because you can only get the value of the parameters from a parameterInfo array and not each parameterInfo (parameterInfo has no GetValue). There has to be a better way to do this.

**EDIT**

There was A LOT of great answers, and each of them worked, so thank you to everyone.

Comment: `GetValue(0)` or rather `GetValue(i)`?

Comment: fixed it, I pasted my testing version and forgot to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
 return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters().ToArray <object>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how I missed the "ToArray" when I was looking at this in visual studio. Reasons not to program at 3 Am in the morning!

Answer (score 0):

```
return Enumerable.Repeat<object>(parameterInfoList.GetValue(0), parameterInfoList.Count).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `parameterInfoList.GetValue(0)` must actually be `parameterInfoList.GetValue(i)`?

```
var parameterInfoList = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
return Enumerable.Range(0, parameterInfoList.Count()).Select(x => parameterInfoList(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume that you want to return the parameter-list of the method which was passed as argument to this method but you're always returning the parameter of `GenerateParameters` itself. So instead of `parameterInfoList` you should use `executingMethod`.
2. You are only adding the first element to the parameter array, `GetValue(0)` instead of `GetValue(i)`.

But since you only want to return the `ParameterInfo[]` isn't it as easy as this?

```
private static ParameterInfo[] GenerateParameters(MethodBase executingMethod)
{
    return executingMethod.GetParameters().ToArray();
}
```

Maybe i've misunderstood your requirement since this is a unnecessary method.